# Save the user input data for long time

Tags: android

I am writing an app to save password with a log in interface. The user can change the log in password. I use the following code to save the password, so that the password will not reset when the app relaunch.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
savedInstanceState.putString("pwd", currentPwd);
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    currentPwd = savedInstanceState.getString("pwd");
}
```

But I found that it can only save the password for a while. When I wait it for a long time, about 1 hours, without reboot the mobile, it will reset my password.

How to save the password so that it will not reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to save the data using sharedpreferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs =
     getSharedPreferences("myprefname",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("pwd", "thepassword");
editor.commit();
```

then you can retreive it:

```
SharedPreferences prefs =
    getSharedPreferences("myprefname",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String password=prefs.getString("pwd",null);
```

Comment: I still have problems when I wait for 1 hours. My code like this now:
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("setting", 0);
currentPwd = settings.getString("pwd", "abc");
}

Comment: @Override
public void onStop(){
super.onStop();
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("setting", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("pwd", currentPwd);
editor.commit();
} Any problems do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You can save that type of information for a long time using `sharedPreference`.

```
public class PreferenceData 
{
    static final String PREF_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) 
    {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    }

    public static void setUserPassword(Context ctx, String userPassword) 
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_USER_PASSWORD, userPassword);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getUserPassword(Context ctx) 
    {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_USER_PASSWORD, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem as you or did have. I simply used Shared_Prefs. It saves the login data in an XML file and you read and write to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem as you or did have. I simply used Shared_Prefs. It saves the login data in an XML file and you read and write to it.

Here's the Android writeup: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

To write:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("key1", username);
            editor.putString("key2", password);
            editor.commit();
```

To Read:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String username = settings.getString("key1", null);
        String password = settings.getString("key2", null);
```